# Building a typewriter generator that defines the font-wight depending on typing speed

Tags: javascript, css, codepen

This is solved: https://codepen.io/danborjesson/pen/qGjMzw

**EDITED:**

I'm building a text generator that will change the font weight depending on the speed you type. This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danborjesson/pen/qGZGgG) showing what I have so far.

It contains a function that starts a timer each time a key is pressed and a way to change the font's weight at the same action. However, not dependent on each other.

Is it possible to get the value from this javascript:

```
    var last;
var output = $('#output');
$('#text').on('input', function() {
    var n = new Date()
    output.text((last - n) + ' ms');
    last = n;
});
```

In to this, instead of 900, to simplify.

```
function myFunction(event) {
  document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "900";
}
```

I can't find a way! All help is appreciated!

/R

Comment: Clarify what you have made and what problem you are facing. You should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before expecting help, also check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Cray I understand Cray. I will shape my post better and I hope that it will become more clear what I need help with along the way.

Comment: 1) If you want each typed letter to be of a different boldness, then a simple textarea is not enough. 2) you will need JavaScript to measure the time between keystrokes and adjust the font-weight accordingly, and 3) never use `font-variation-settings` for properties that other CSS properties exist for.

Comment: I understand @MrLister , I'm trying it all here and would gladly take more of your good tips. is <input id="txt" a better way to to it? Do I need to add some jQuery for measure time? I'm pretty new to this but I'm wanting to learn.

Comment: @Cray is this better?

Comment: @MrLister now I have more than from the beginning. Thanks for your guide lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it overly complicated for yourself. Don't mix inline js with one in file. Just add a second listener for your `text` field and use the values you need. Also it seems `keyup` would be the event you need, not `keypress`. Another thing you should check is the calculation of `ms`, you probably meant to get a positive value, which would be `n - last`.

```js
let last, ms, n;
let output = $('#output');

$('#text').on('input', function() {
    n = new Date();
    ms = n - last;
    output.text(ms + ' ms');
    last = n;
});

$('#text').on('keyup', function() {
    console.log(ms);
    this.style.fontWeight = "900";
});

let i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keypress(function(){
    $("span").text(i += 1 );
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://use.typekit.net/obu1vfn.css:);

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}

list {
    font-family: orator-std, monospace;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 2rem;
}

button, input {
    border: none;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
     font-family: ibm-plex-sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #11111;
    
    /**transition: font-weight .5s ease-in-out;
    &:hover,
    &.be-bold {
        font-weight: (900);
        cursor: pointer;
   
    }**/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<list>
//HOVER_THE_BOX:
<br>
//KEYPRESSES: <span>0</span> TIMES
<br>
//TIME SINCE LAST PRESS:
<div id="output"></div></list>

<input id="text" placeholder="Type here">
```

Comment: Thanks Cray! You are my hero! Now I have created a long if chain so that makes the font-weight bolder if you write really fast. Maybe this can be done in another way but I don't know how and this will work for now.

Comment: I understand that you are really good at this and now when you know what I'm doing I wonder if you know if there's a way to store the letters you write. So that the font-weight doesn't just changes on the new text and not on what's been written.

Comment: You can't do it inside the input element, but if you display the typed text in another element then yes. For example use a `div` and append `span` elements to it `<div><span style="font-weight: 900;">My</span><span style="font-weight: 100;">text</span></div>`. You can use `change` eventlistener to modify contents in `div`. It would probably be reasonable to use classes instead of style attributes, so that you can verify if you need to enter a new span with new font-weight or append to previous text. Also remember you should handle delete and other events that are not typing.

Comment: Thanks again Cray! I am so close my goal now. I have now a new div box that shows the same text from the big input field. I'm not so familiar with event listener but did check it up and I understand how to create an event listener to change the font weight in the same way that the big text. But not how to store it. Can you give me some search words that can keep me going. I'm so grateful. Ps. gonna style the design later hehe.

Comment: Is it possible to use an event listener Cray to form individual values of my output box I've created? I do not know how to use them in this case. And my way right now changes the whole text, which I understand is wrong right from the start.

Comment: One [idea](https://jsfiddle.net/sp1a62eb/) on how to do it. Store each letter (or part of string that has same style) in a span as i previously said. As i previously said you will have to handle delete, arrowkey events aswell which will be a little harder.

Comment: I see! I’m really grateful for your tips. I did spend like 12 hours  yesterday just to understand the eventlisteners , but I didn’t. Even whit the new comment I don’t see which code that will provoke my output div-box. Is it so hard or should I just give up?

Comment: Definately not an easy task to do if you don't understand simple javascript. But you really need an eventlistener to add each new character to div, with a new style. `keyup` and `change` should work best.

Comment: I understand that it is a lot of trial and error but now, whit your suggestion I have come to this Js: 
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
 document.getElementById("new-content").innerHTML = " " + x;
});

Comment: Okay I understand where you probably got confused. You were using jQuery before, but now you are trying to use plain javascript. `$('#text').on('keyup', function() { })` is eventlistener just like `document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keyup", function() { })`. But yes your approach is kinda correct, however you should be appending new text to `new-content`, right now you are replacing it all.

Comment: https://codepen.io/danborjesson/pen/MdJYZd now I have an a append, I think. But it takes everything in the box and duplicates it.

Comment: I suggest `$("#textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
  $("#content").append(e.key)
});`. Also you can check for delete/backspace/arrowkeys with `e.keyCode`

Comment: Sounds perfect! And for the span classes, i’m totalt lost. How to adjust only the already written text and not for everything.. is it hard? How do you think it cost to pay someone for it. Need it for a presentation. Next week.

Comment: https://codepen.io/danborjesson/pen/zQNMeL latest. Trying to prevent delete/backspace/arrowkeys and to change span on the written text.